# Drupal 8 - Adding/Creating Menu Item with HTML in it

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-8

I'm creating a website using Drupal 8. I want to create a menu item link that I could add HTML/Javascript code in it (I'm trying to display a widget that expands on click in the menu rather than displaying it in its own block next to the menu). The only way I could see to add a menu item is to link to a page.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could work with a derivative. This lets you customize pretty much everything about it and control what is to be made. An example below:

> Note: I am assuming you have a general knowledge of custom modules. If not follow [this link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules)

Create the following file in your custom module:

```
# my_module.links.menu.yml
my_module.custom_links:
  deriver: \Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Derivative\CustomLinkDerivative
```

And now for the derivative class (Located under my_module/src/Plugin/Derivative)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Derivative;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\Derivative\DeriverBase;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\Discovery\ContainerDeriverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class CustomLinkDerivative extends DeriverBase implements ContainerDeriverInterface {

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, $base_plugin_id) {
    return new static();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition) {
    $links['custom_menulink'] = [
      'title' => t('Custom menulink'),
      'menu_name' => 'main',
      'route_name' => 'entity.node.canonical',
      'parent' => footer,
      'route_parameters' => [
        'node' => 1,
      ]
    ] + $base_plugin_definition;

    return $links;
  }
}
```

> Note: Derivatives get triggered during rebuild of cache!

This just creates a link in the footer that directs to node 1. You can add all sort of stuff and logic to your liking. Hope this helps you :)